# How to place tkinter button in specific place (in pixels)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For the past few days I have been trying to create a Python script that serves as a dashboard. However, I cannot figure out how to create a Button that is in a specific place (ex. 50, 50) but cannot figure it out.

```py
b = Button(root, text="some button", height=50, width=50, compound='c')
b.pack(x=50, y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is the right place?

Comment: Hi. Tkinters geometry manager use pack(), grid() and place(). Please read the documetation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

class App():
    """ App class """

    def __init__(self, master):
        """ init """
        self.master = master
        self.my_button_1 = Button(self.master, text="Press", command=self.passing)
        self.my_button_1.place(x=50, y=100)
    
    def passing(self):
        print("Button pressed")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Geometry manager")
    root.geometry("600x400")   
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This will place the left-top button corner 50 pixels in the X-axis and 100 pixels in the Y-axis. You can achieve the same with grid() manager as well but you have to be carefully with columns and rows.

place( place-options):
x, y, height, width, anchor, bordermode, relx, rely, relheight, relwidth

You can find more info in the documentation.